# css active submenu should show whole submenu

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with my vertical navigation:

```
<div class="menu-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/menu1">Menu1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu1">Submenu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu2">Submenu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu3">Submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
...
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.menu-container a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
.menu-container a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu-container li:hover > .sub-menu{
    display:block;
}
.sub-menu{
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:6px;
}
ul.sub-menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu-container  > ul.sub-menu a{
    display:block;
    background:#ddd;
}
.menu-container  > .sub-menu:active{
    display:block;
    background:#ddd;
}
```

If I hover the menu the sub-menu show up. Now, in addition I would like, that if e.g. the submenu1 is active that the whole submenu stays openend. Can I realize that with CSS?

Greets,
Yab86

Comment: Are you asking if the user navigates to the link that is submenu1, that the submenu stays open on that page? If so, you can't do that with just CSS, you'll need to use a server-side or jQuery solution.

Comment: Exactly. :-) Sorry for my english. Do you have an example?

Comment: Your English is great! I wanted to make sure I answered you correctly. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using PHP. You need to create a page variable before the `<html>` like this:

`<?php $page = 'menu1'; ?>
<html>
<!-- rest of HTML below here-->`

That php code gets put on top of every submenu page that shares a common main parent menu. So in your example, `submenu1, submenu2, and submenu3` would have the same variable. In this example, `menu1`. What this does, is allows you to add a CSS class of `current` to the submenu parent `ul`.

Here's the HTML with the PHP in place:

```
<?php $page = "menu1"?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
<div class="menu-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/menu1">Menu1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu <?php if($page == 'menu1')echo 'current'; ?>">
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu1">Submenu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu2">Submenu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu3">Submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
      <li><a href="/menu1">Menu2</a>
<ul class="sub-menu <?php if($page == 'menu2')echo 'current'; ?>">
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu4">Submenu4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu5">Submenu5</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu6">Submenu6</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
    </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS that would keep it open:

```
.menu-container li:hover > .sub-menu,
.menu-container .current {
    display:block;
}
```

When the HTML outputs to the browser, this is what it would actually look like if you were on any of the submenu1,2,3 pages:

```
<div class="menu-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/menu1">Menu1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu current">
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu1">Submenu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu2">Submenu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu3">Submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
      <li><a href="/menu1">Menu2</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu4">Submenu4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu5">Submenu5</a></li>
  <li><a href="/menu1/submenu6">Submenu6</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hopefully this helps you out.